# Redirect a subdomain to another host and a specific route

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-route53, aws-route53

I have an internally (on-site) hosted site that will be down for maintenance.

Currently the subdomain that routes to this site is setup on Route53

I want to redirect my internal site (internal-site.my-web-site.com) to (my-web-site.com/maintenance.html)

my-web-site.com is hosted in s3

Comment: Set up a hosting for internal-site.my-web-site.com like you did for my-web-site.com.  Redirect all requests.   Test and get it working, then you can switch DNS over to that site for the maintenance window.

Comment: You mention that `my-web-site.com` site is hosted in S3. Does that mean you have static pages in an S3 bucket and you have [Configured a static website using a custom domain registered with Route 53 - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)? You _might_ be able to create a CNAME that points `internal-site.my-web-site.com` to `my-web-site.com`, but you can't point it to a particular path since DNS names only resolve to IP addresses, not a path.